Struggling with transistor-based white noise generators
I'm trying to make a white noise generator, but I'm struggling to get the correct output.
I'm following this schematic:

After this, I send it through an LM358 to amplify it, though my results are not what I was hoping for.
I'll attach photos below showing my circuits and oscilloscope results (if they're not "legible" I am open to attempting to take clear ones.)




Can you include a schematic of the circuits on the breadboard? There seems to be two different setups, the first with one IC and another with two ICs.

That linked schematic is missing an important connection. Pin 3 (+IN) must be grounded.

@ChesterGillon sorry for the lack of clarity, sent the wrong photo with the first one.

@Mattman944 When i ground Pin 3, the voltage on my oscilloscope drops down to 0? Is there something else wrong within the breadboard?

@delusionalguy - the DC level at the op-amp output (pin 6) should be zero. The noise will be AC.

You say you are not getting the "correct" output, and the results are not what you were hoping for.  In what way is the circuit not performing correctly, what results are you getting, and what results were you hoping for?

@AnalogKid I guess I just had a different - or more accurately incorrect - expectations of the result circuit? What I currently see is but a straight line, and assumed that by passing 5v through the signal, I'd end up with a waveform with more fluctuations? Really sorry for the confusion caused by my inexperience..

@delusionalguy - the signal level may be fairly low, have you set the scope to a sensitive scale such as 50 mV/div?

@delusionalguy - Are you using a bipolar power supply or two power supplies? This circuit requires a +V, and a -V, both referenced to "ground" (circuit ground, not earth ground). Power supplies, unfortunately, are labeled +/-.

The first thing to address is that there are no guarantees regarding the reverse breakdown voltage of the base-emitter junction of any transistor. It could be anywhere over 5V depending on the transistor model. I have no idea of the highest ever recorded reverse-breakdown voltage of, say, a 2N3904, but I'll bet it's more than 10V. That means you'll need a supply well beyond that to guarantee that the junction breaks down. If you are using ±5V supplies (for a total potential difference of 10V), then there's a good chance of failure. You might need to try several several examples of the same model, and different models too. Here's how you determine if the transistor is OK for your circuit (I show ±5V supplies, but you should replace them with your own intended values):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The voltage you wish to see across resistor R1 is 2V or more. If you see close to 0V on VM1, then the junction is not breaking down at all. Less than 2V indicates that you are a little too close to the breakdown threshold, which will change over time and temperature.
It strikes me that maybe you got the supplies the wrong way around for this stage; the transistor's base-emitter junction must be reverse biased, meaning that the base must be more negative, connected to the negative supply. Check your wiring.

Gain-bandwidth-product of the LM358 is 1MHz. You have configured your op-amp to have a gain of \$-\frac{1M\Omega}{2.2k\Omega}=-450\$, which limits signal bandwidth to \$\frac{1MHz}{450}=2.2kHz\$. This causes gain to roll off well below that frequency. That may not be a problem, but for the noise to be closer to "white" than "brown", you'll need more bandwidth.
A single stage with gain 450 is also going to produce a significant DC output offset, which can cause clipping on one side of the signal swing but not the other. The input offset voltage of the LM358 can be as bad as 7mV (or worse at extreme temperatures), information you can find in the LM358 datasheet, page 6. That input offset is subject to closed-loop gain, meaning that the output could shifted  up or down from zero by as much as \$7mV \times 450 = 3.2V\$. When the author of that schematic wrote "any single op-amp", perhaps what he should have written is "any op-amp with input offset voltage under 1mV". This can be mitigated by using two AC-coupled stages, which I'll talk about in a moment.
Another issue is that the 2.2kΩ input resistance to the amplifier is a heavy load on the noise source. Ideally you would want to lighten that load, which would necessitate increasing the 2.2kΩ resistance, but that would decrease gain. Happily, though, it would also increase bandwidth, which is good.
Since you have two op-amps in a single LM358 package, it's possible to use two stages of amplification, instead of one, which would address all these problems. We can achieve the same gain by cascading two stages of gain \$\sqrt{450}=21\$, and simultaneously increase input impedance and bandwidth by a factor of 21:

simulate this circuit
The stages are AC coupled by capacitor C2, so that any DC offset from OA1 is cancelled, and the DC output offset from OA2 will not exceed \$7mA \times 21 = 0.15V\$.
You may find that the gain of 450 is too much, and OA2 output saturates. In that case you may reduce gain by reducing the feedback resistances R3 and R5. For instance, if you cut them in half, you cut gain by \$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}\$. For reasons to do with op-amp input bias current and susceptibility to interference, I would not recommend using feedback resistances greater than 1MΩ.

You could also try buffering the the noise source with a unity-gain emitter-follower; a single extra transistor and resistor. In this way you might still be able to get away with using only one op-amp:

simulate this circuit
Q2's base looks more like 2MΩ to the previous (noise) stage, and will attenuate far less. Also, you can set gain by altering R2 (and/or R3) to your heart's content, since the emitter follower output is much "stronger".

I built the circuit with an LM358 and it works. Be sure to use the correct pin numbers for an LM358. See my modified schematic. I used +/- 10 V supplies. It worked down to +/- 5 V, but any lower, it didn't. So, you want voltage supplies closer to +/- 10 V.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
First, I used a BC546, this is commonly available.

Next, I used the oldest transistor that I could quickly find, a 50-year-old Sprague TN-59. This has more noise, agreeing with the other answers, a poor transistor will generally have more noise.


A general-purpose transistor is usually a rather low-noise device when used as a gain stage. It is somewhat finicky to use as an audio noise source. The reverse B-E breakdown is not reliable. You'd have to select the parts that work well. By selecting I mean test each individual transistor across a range of voltages and temperatures to ensure they work as you need them to. Reverse breakdown is temperature sensitive so you may get breakdown at room temperature but not if the band is playing in a cold garage :)
2N7000s are rather dependable noise sources when working as common-source amplifiers. It makes them unusable as gain stages for most audio amplifier applications. But they have an advantage here.
I would suggest using a 2N7000 as an amplifier of its own noise, followed by a 20x gain LM358-based amplifier stage. You can use as many op-amp stages as you need, as long as their gain is 20 or less, to retain enough bandwidth.
The lower the LM358 gain, the more white the noise will be. LM358s really struggle with wideband audio signals.
